# How to update a rows with same prodID on a UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I get the following error: 
"Can't update table 'Product' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

```
CREATE TRIGGER `SalesDB`.`updateSum` AFTER UPDATE ON SalesDB.Product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE totalStock INT;

  SELECT SUM(stock) 
      INTO totalStock
      FROM Product
      WHERE Product.prodID= NEW.prodID;

  UPDATE Product SET StockSum = totalStock
      WHERE  prodID = NEW.prodID;
END;
```

I understand that there is a recursive issue, but how do I do something like this? Is there a way to use triggers to do this kind of thing? Should this be done in a Stored Procedure instead, and how do I run the stroed procedure on a Update Product event?

I need to update the stock of a product and then go thru all rows that have the same prodID calculate the SUM and Update the SumTotal field of all the rows.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in real-world terms? Some sample table data may also help.

Comment: It sounds like the better approach might be to keep item stock levels in a separate related table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** Unfortunately you can't do this in MySql due to the limitations of triggers implementation.

Possible options are:

1. Create stored procedure and call it after each update on Product table
2. Store stockSum in a separate table (e.g. ProductStock), use triggers (INSERT, UPDATE) to update stockSum values, create a view on joined Product and ProductStock
3. Use MySql events or a cron job to update stockSum in Product table if some delay is acceptable

IMHO best approach is 2 separating Product and ProductStock tables:

ProductStock might look like this

```
CREATE TABLE ProductStock
(
  prodID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  stockSum decimal(12, 3)
);
```

Now triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_product_update
AFTER UPDATE ON Product 
FOR EACH ROW
CALL sp_updateProductStock(NEW.prodID);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_product_insert
AFTER INSERT ON Product 
FOR EACH ROW
CALL sp_updateProductStock(NEW.prodID);
```

and a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_updateProductStock(IN ProductID INT)
REPLACE INTO ProductStock (prodID, stockSum) 
SELECT ProductID, 
       (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(stock, 0)) 
          FROM Product
         WHERE prodID = ProductID);
```

And finally a view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Product AS
SELECT p.id, p.prodID, ... , p.stock, s.stockSum
  FROM Product p JOIN ProductStock s
    ON p.prodID = s.prodID
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fe56/1)** example

Comment: I need to Update a product stock, and then go thru all the rows that have the same productID and update their SumStock. That will only update the current row, not all rows. and it's triggered Before the Update, I want After Update

Comment: @AdamSurfari You can't do that directly in MySql. See updated answer for possible options.

Comment: Thank you for the updated anwser, great reply! I agree. I will have to convince my manager that creating a seperate table is the correct thing to do. This was actually my first solution, but adding one column would "have less impact" to the data model. I think this is the only clean way to do it. Keep a separate table.

Comment: I am getting an error: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'"

Comment: @AdamSurfari You're more than welcome. As the error says you probably already have another trigger for the table with the same action (INSERT or UPDATE). MySql allows only one trigger per table per action. So delete your previously defined triggers and then create a new one.

Comment: Actually it was TOAD for MySQL that caused the error, it did not display any triggers, I closed it and saw that there was indeed a trigger already created for Update. TOAD kills me, it's free but so buggy!